# What are the challenges involved in creating an app like InstaMapper for android

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, maps, tracking

http://www.instamapper.com/android

I am planning to dive into android dev and i have a pretty good java and web-dev background.
i was planning to develop an InstaMapper type of application and i need to know the challenges in so basically the things involved in gps tracking and displaying the information on web page..

Answer (score 0):

In simple words,

1. You need a web service.
2. You need an android app.

Your app will collect the (Latitude,Longitude) pair from your GPS receiver and sends it to your web app.

Your web app will get this values and store them in a database.

To display the path from (Lat,Long) pair, you need to implement Google Maps API inside your web pages. (Google Maps API: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/)

Comment: thank you !.. i was worried about making the server request the app's co-ordinate pair any details on how to accomplish that..?

Comment: Actually when you are accessing your location through GPS in your device, you are getting the (Latitude, Longitude) pair. You can send this value to your server by just making a request, like this:

`http://yourserver.com/addpoint.php?lat=6.77339&long=22.478949`

You are just opening this URL as usual as you open any other URL. You are collecting this values in the file `addpoint.php`, like this:

$latitude = $_GET['lat'];
$longitude = $_GET['long'];